How do I get the PID of the process that killed my socket?
We're getting a situation where we're running Java code that consumes APIs on another server.
On Macs - this runs fine.
With a recent patch update - the Windows boxes can open a socket (you can see this with telnet to the socket) but the Java socket is killed almost straight away. ("Connection reset").
We strongly suspect this is a Windows Defender policy but are trying to prove it.
My question is: How do I get the PID of the process that killed my socket?

If telnet shows "connected" before reset, then it shouldn't be firewall at least. "Connection reset" means the server side sent you a reset - see the (answers here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset] for most of the reasons that can happen like timeout or bad data
